# Sub total of recycler view nodes keeps increasing in android app

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**MY ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I am making an android app with firebase Realtime database. I am getting sum of the firebase nodes in side recycler view. I have a text view out side the recycler view where I am getting the sub total of the values of the recycler view. **MY PROBLEM** is that I cannot get the actual sum and also the sum keeps increasing when I scroll up and down. Here is my Main activity JAVA code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase myfire;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<entry> options;
    int totalEarned = 0;
    int totalSpent = 0;
    int totalSaved=0;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Are you sure to exit?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Play", (dialog1, which) -> {

        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Exit", (dialog12, which) -> {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            MainActivity.this.finish();

        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private String getUID() {
        FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (mUser != null) {
            String strUID = mUser.getUid();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strUID)) {
                return strUID;
            }
        }

        return "";

    }
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //==============
        final RecyclerView userlist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.idRecycleView);
        myfire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        userlist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //==================
        final TextView tvTotalIncome = findViewById(R.id.idTotalIncome);
        final TextView tvTotalExpanse = findViewById(R.id.idTotalExpanse);
        final TextView tvTotalSaved = findViewById(R.id.idTotalSaved);
        //==================

        final FloatingActionButton btnBudget = findViewById(R.id.idCreateBudget);
        myfire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final String strUID = getUID();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strUID)) {
            //handle case of null UID
        }

        final Intent i = getIntent();
        final String month = Objects.requireNonNull(i.getExtras()).getString("Month");
        //-------------------------------
        btnBudget.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent o;
            o = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddBudgetActivity.class);
            o.putExtra("Month",month);
            startActivity(o);
            finish();

        });

        if (type.equals("Income")) {
            try {
                totalEarned = (totalEarned+sum);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            }

            tvTotalIncome.setText("-)"+String.valueOf( totalEarned));
            holder.btnIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circlegreen);
            holder.tvEntry.setText("(+)"+String.valueOf(sum)  );

            try {
                totalSaved = (totalEarned-totalSpent);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            }
            tvTotalSaved.setText("(=)"+String.valueOf( totalSaved));
        }else if (type.equals("Expanse")) {

            try {
                totalSpent = (totalSpent+sum);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            }
            tvTotalExpanse.setText("-)"+String.valueOf( totalSpent));
            holder.btnIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circlered);
            holder.tvEntry.setText("(-)"+String.valueOf(sum)  );
            try {
                totalSaved = (totalEarned-totalSpent);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            }
            tvTotalSaved.setText("(=)"+String.valueOf( totalSaved));
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Something Went Wrong !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //======================


        myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(month);
//-------------------------
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<entry>()
                .setQuery(myRef, entry.class)
                .build();
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entry, holder_menu> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entry, holder_menu>(options) {


            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull holder_menu holder, final int i, @NonNull @NotNull entry model) {
                final String title = getRef(i).getKey();
                assert title != null;


                myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(month).child(title).child("Budget");
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        int budget = 0;

                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {

                            final String stData1 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData1").getValue())).toString();
                            final String stData2 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData2").getValue())).toString();
                            final String stData3 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData3").getValue())).toString();
                            final String stData4 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData4").getValue())).toString();

                            entry basic = new entry(stData1, stData2, stData3, stData4);

                            String first = stData2.substring(0, 1);
                            holder.btnIcon.setText(first);
                            holder.tvHead.setText(stData2);
                            String type;
                            type=(stData3);
                            holder.tvBudget.setText("@" + stData4);
                            int amount = 0;

                            //important line
                            try {
                                amount = (Integer.parseInt(stData4));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            }
                            //======================
                            budget = amount;

                            myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(month).child(title).child("Entry");
                            final int finalBudget = budget;
                            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                int sum = 0;
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        String section = data.child("stData2").getValue(String.class);
                                        String value = data.child("stData4").getValue(String.class);
                                        assert value != null;
                                        int total = 0;

                                        //important line
                                        try {
                                            total = (Integer.parseInt(value));
                                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                        }
                                        //======================
                                        sum = sum + total;
                                        //==============
                                        //======================
                                        if (section.equals("Saving")) {
                                            holder.tvHead.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.saving));

                                        }else if (section.equals("Paying")) {

                                            holder.tvHead.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.paying));
                                        }else if (section.equals("Using")) {

                                            holder.tvHead.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.using));
                                        }else if (section.equals("Earning")) {
                                            holder.tvHead.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.earning));

                                        }else if (section.equals("Taking")) {

                                            holder.tvHead.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.taking));
                                        }else if (section.equals("Drawing")) {

                                            holder.tvHead.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.drawing));

                                        }else {
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Something Went Wrong !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    holder.tvEntry.setText("(+)" + String.valueOf(sum)  );
                                    holder.tvBalance.setText("(=)" + String.valueOf(finalBudget - sum) );

                                    //important line
                                    holder.btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            Intent o;
                                            o = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewHistoryActivity.class);
                                            o.putExtra("Title", title);
                                            o.putExtra("Month", month);
                                            o.putExtra("Type", type);
                                            startActivity(o);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            if (type.equals("Income")) {
                                                Intent o;
                                                o = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EntryIncomeActivity.class);
                                                o.putExtra("Title", title);
                                                o.putExtra("Month", month);
                                                o.putExtra("Type", type);
                                                startActivity(o);
                                                finish();

                                            }else if (type.equals("Expanse")) {
                                                Intent o;
                                                o = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EntryExpanseActivity.class);
                                                o.putExtra("Title", title);
                                                o.putExtra("Month", month);
                                                o.putExtra("Type", type);
                                                startActivity(o);
                                                finish();

                                            }else {
                                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Something Went Wrong !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }



                                        }
                                    });
                                    if (type.equals("Income")) {
                                        try {
                                            totalEarned = (totalEarned+sum);
                                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                        }

                                        tvTotalIncome.setText("-)"+String.valueOf( totalEarned));
                                        holder.btnIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circlegreen);
                                        holder.tvEntry.setText("(+)"+String.valueOf(sum)  );

                                        try {
                                            totalSaved = (totalEarned-totalSpent);
                                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                        }
                                        tvTotalSaved.setText("(=)"+String.valueOf( totalSaved));
                                    }else if (type.equals("Expanse")) {

                                        try {
                                            totalSpent = (totalSpent+sum);
                                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                        }
                                        tvTotalExpanse.setText("-)"+String.valueOf( totalSpent));
                                        holder.btnIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circlered);
                                        holder.tvEntry.setText("(-)"+String.valueOf(sum)  );
                                        try {
                                            totalSaved = (totalEarned-totalSpent);
                                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                        }
                                        tvTotalSaved.setText("(=)"+String.valueOf( totalSaved));
                                    }else {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Something Went Wrong !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    //======================



                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
                    }

                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public holder_menu onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);
                return new holder_menu(v);
            }
        };

        adapter.startListening();
        userlist.setAdapter(adapter);


    }



}
```

**EDITED QUESTION** As per @androidLearner 's suggestion

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase myfire;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    int totalEarned = 0;
    int totalSpent = 0;
    int totalSaved=0;
    madapter adapter;


    String iconsData;
    String headsData;
    int budgetsData=0;
    int enteriesData=0;
    int balancesData=0;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Are you sure to exit?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Play", (dialog1, which) -> {

        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Exit", (dialog12, which) -> {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            MainActivity.this.finish();

        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private String getUID() {
        FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (mUser != null) {
            String strUID = mUser.getUid();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strUID)) {
                return strUID;
            }
        }

        return "";

    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //==============
        final RecyclerView userlist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.idRecycleView);
        myfire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        userlist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //==================
        final TextView tvTotalIncome = findViewById(R.id.idTotalIncome);
        final TextView tvTotalExpanse = findViewById(R.id.idTotalExpanse);
        final TextView tvTotalSaved = findViewById(R.id.idTotalSaved);
        //==================

        final FloatingActionButton btnBudget = findViewById(R.id.idCreateBudget);
        myfire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final String strUID = getUID();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strUID)) {
            //handle case of null UID
        }

        final Intent i = getIntent();
        final String month = Objects.requireNonNull(i.getExtras()).getString("Month");

        //-------------------------------
        btnBudget.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent o;
            o = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddBudgetActivity.class);
            o.putExtra("Month",month);
            startActivity(o);
            finish();

        });


//&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&---new method

        myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(month);
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String title = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    assert title != null;
                    myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(month).child(title).child("Budget");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    final String stData1 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData1").getValue())).toString();
                    final String stData2 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData2").getValue())).toString();
                    final String stData3 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData3").getValue())).toString();
                    final String stData4 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData4").getValue())).toString();

                    entry basic = new entry(stData1, stData2, stData3, stData4);

                    iconsData = stData2.substring(0, 1);
                    headsData=stData2;
                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------entry
                    myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(month).child(title).child("Entry");
                    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        int sum = 0;
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String section = data.child("stData2").getValue(String.class);
                                String value = data.child("stData4").getValue(String.class);
                                assert value != null;
                                int total = 0;
 try {
                                                            total=(Integer.parseInt(value));
                                                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                                        }
                                //==============
                                  sum=sum+total;
                            }
                                 enteriesData=sum;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
                        }
                    });

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
            }

        });
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
            }
        });
          //&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&------NewMethod
        balancesData=budgetsData-enteriesData;
        ArrayList<String> iconList = new ArrayList<>();
        iconList.add(iconsData);
        ArrayList<String> headList= new ArrayList<>();
        headList.add(headsData);
        ArrayList<Integer> budgetList = new ArrayList<>();
        budgetList.add(budgetsData);
        ArrayList<Integer> entryList = new ArrayList<>();
        entryList.add(enteriesData);
        ArrayList<Integer> balanceList = new ArrayList<>();
        balanceList.add(balancesData);

        adapter = new madapter ( this, iconList,headList,budgetList,entryList,balanceList);
        userlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

**RECYCLER VIEW Adapter**

```
public class madapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<madapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> stricon;
    private List<String> strhead;
    private List<Integer> intbudget;
    private List<Integer> intentry;
    private List<Integer> intbalance;

    //---
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor

    public madapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String> iconList, ArrayList<String> headList, ArrayList<Integer> budgetList, ArrayList<Integer> entryList, ArrayList<Integer> balanceList) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity);
        this.stricon = iconList;
        this.strhead = headList;
        this.intbudget = budgetList;
        this.intentry = entryList;
        this.intbalance= balanceList;
    }


    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String icons = stricon.get(position);
        String heads = strhead.get(position);
        int budgets = intbudget.get(position);
        int entries = intentry.get(position);
        int balances = intbalance.get(position);
        holder.btnIcon.setText(icons);
        holder.tvHead.setText(heads);
        holder.tvBudget.setText(String.valueOf(budgets));
        holder.tvEntry.setText(String.valueOf(entries));
        holder.tvBalance.setText(String.valueOf(balances));

    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stricon.size();

    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public Button btnIcon;
        public TextView tvHead;
        public TextView tvBudget;
        public TextView tvEntry;
        public TextView tvBalance;
        public Button btnView;
        public Button btnAdd;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            btnIcon= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idIcon);
            tvHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idHead);
            tvBudget = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idBudget);
            tvEntry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idEntry);
            tvBalance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idBalance);
            btnView= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idView);
            btnAdd = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idAdd);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return stricon.get(id);


    }



    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

**THE NEW PROBLEM AFTER EDITING**

I am not able to get any data from firebase to my array list by the method datasnapshot. But yes my recycler view shows data if I add hardcore text or numbers to my list manually.

This is the crash report

```
2021-05-24 00:07:12.368 19933-19933/com.myappname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myappname, PID: 19933
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.myappname.model.rvAdapter.onBindViewHolder(mAdapter.java:54)
        at com.myappname.model.rvAdapter.onBindViewHolder(mAdapter.java:16)2021-05-24 .......................................
```

Comment: You don't seem to understand the design of ViewHolders: they only **represent** an item from your dataset and should in no way store anything aside from volatile view state as during scroll they will be recycled and used to display (bind to) another item. This means items that are "out of view" will have no ViewHolder bound to them so you cannot "get" them either.

Comment: sum keep increasing because every time onBindviewholder getting value from firebase when you scroll up and down.So Move all firebase callback methods from onBindViewHolder to your activity then from activity get values from firebase  then set to recyclerview adapter.then get actual total.

Comment: Please update you question with separated mainActivty and recycllerviewAdapter.

Comment: so you want the total number of items in recycler-view?

Comment: you are almost done. still keep increasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set Adapter after got data from firebase

```
         myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            int sum = 0;
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    
    
                                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    String section = data.child("stData2").getValue(String.class);
                                    String value = data.child("stData4").getValue(String.class);
                                    assert value != null;
                                    int total = 0;
    
                                    //==============
                                      sum=sum+total;
                                }
                                     enteriesData=sum;
//Send your data to adapter as per your need from here
          adapter = new madapter ( this, iconList,headList,budgetList,entryList,balanceList);
            userlist.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
```

Comment: asking about which one ?@user14253444

Comment: am not sure about what is balenceList.if balenceList contains balancesData ,move this logic(balancesData=budgetsData-enteriesData) to onDataChange() method.Note:do all your  calculations inside onDataChange().@user14253444

Comment: for instance you have array size 2 ,when you try to get(2) value will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.because nothing is in 3rd place.@user14253444